# Does having a real valued cauchy sequence on a function in a compact space imply the function is continous on that space?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, power-series, compactness, cauchy-sequences

I had to prove for a homework assignment this function

$$          s_n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n  (-1)^i \frac{ x^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}  $$

is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the sup norm for $$ s_n : [-M,M] \to \mathbb{R} $$ where M is any positive real number.

The goal is to show this sequence converges uniformly to the sine function, but the theorem I want to use requires $ s_n $ to be continuous, which I think is obvious because it is a power series and therefore a sum of real valued polynomials. But I wanted to know if there was a direct relationship between having a Cauchy sequence on a power series that defines a function and the function itself being continuous.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean Cauchy sequences w.r.t to the sup norm? (I.e., the metric would be $d(f,g)=\sup |f(x)-g(x)|$.)

Comment: Yes. Thank you for pointing that out.